# FOS user bundle is activated but how keep everybody out in direct access to a specific path?

Tags: symfony, authentication, bundle

I've added FOS bundle to my symfony project via composer. I can now login and logout with no problem everything works fine. But there is something that I don't know about and that is how to tell FOS user bundle to check whether user is logged in or not when he/she attempts to access a page?

**To put it simple:** No login page is displayed when user accesses a page in the project. How to force every path to check if user is logged in or not? In case he's not redirect him to login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up your access control in your `app/config/security.yml` so that everything requires a user role except for your login, javascript and css section.

For a site that I have done I have the following..

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/bundles, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/css, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/js, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
#    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
#    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

On this site all users are administrated internally hence the `register` and `resetting` being hidden (the routes don't even exist actually).

Answer (score 3):

You should use secure annotation option in every Controller action, which shows logged in data. This provided by: JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle.

In next example I presume that every user has the ROLE_DATA_VIEW role. User could has more roles, static roles and dynamic roles too.

**Example code:**

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
// ORM or ODM support.
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

// Some useful stuff.
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

// Sensio annotation Route, Method, Template support.
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
// Security!
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;

/**
 * Data Controller
 * Can use parent Route with "at" Route("/data")
 */
class DataController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all logged in data entities.
     *
     * @Route("/logged-in-data/", name="logged_in_data")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     * @Secure("ROLE_DATA_VIEW")
     */
    public function loggedInDataAction()
    {
      // ...
    }
```

**And here is an example of user a specific page, like user profile handling.**

```
   /** 
     * User profile
     *
     * @Route("/user-profile/", name="user_profile")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function profileAction()
    {
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        return array('user' => $user);
    }
```

**You can check in your base twig file, that the login needed function is able to use or not.**

```
{% if app.user and is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') %}
   <div>logged in data, function, etc.</div>
{% endif %}
```